# How to link menu in Odoo to a computed URL

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I need to link a menu item in Odoo to an external link, but this external link is a string stored in model and it is different for every user. I'm not sure how to code this inside the `eval` attribute of field name `url`. Or is this possible?

```
<openerp>
   <data>
        <record id="open_retainer" model="ir.actions.act_url">
            <field name="name">Pay Retainer</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_url</field>
            <field name="target">new</field>
            <field name="url" eval="'some_url' if True else ''"/>
        </record>

        <menuitem
                name="Pay Retainer"
                id="menu_pay_retainer"
                groups="base.group_portal"
                action="open_retainer"
                parent="portal.portal_orders"/>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having as menu, you can try by clicking a button in the user screen and redirect to the specific url.

You can try following:

```
return { 'type': 'ir.actions.act_url', 'url': your_url, 'nodestroy': True, 'target': 'new' }
```

where **'your_url'** is the url string stored for each user.

Comment: I have tried this already and yes, this is working for me. But what I specifically need is that the user does not have to open a dialog that has the button linked to a method. I want that user when clicking on the menu, he will automatically open the external url.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. here is a simple idea on `ir_actions_act_url`
suppose the external link in stored in `res.users` model. to redirect it as per user you need to inherit `ir.actions.act_url` model. and modify the read method. like

```
class ir_actions_act_url(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'ir.actions.act_url'

    def read(self, cr, uid, ids, fields=None, context=None, load='_classic_read'):
        if not context: context = {}
        results = super(ir_actions_act_url, self).read(cr, uid, ids, fields=fields, context=context, load=load)
        if len(ids) == 1:
            user_obj = self.pool.get('res.users')
            user_rec = user_obj.browse(cr, uid, uid, context=context)
            if user_rec.external_link:
                results[0].update({'url':user_rec.external_link})
        return results
```

You can modify the logic as per your requirement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @AtulArvind. I get the logic of your code but I think I just have to modify it a little bit so that this does not apply to every act_url. I will accept this as the answer once I have tried this later.

Answer (score 2):

Example:

Open URL from menu with config parameter

```xml
    <record id="url_website" model="ir.config_parameter">
        <field name="key">url_website</field>
        <field name="value">http://google.com.pe</field>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.actions.server" id="action_open_url">
        <field name="name">action_open_url</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="base.model_res_partner"/>
        <field name="code">
url = env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param('url_website')
action = {"type": "ir.actions.act_url",
          "url": url,
          "target": "new",}
        </field>
    </record>

    <menuitem id="menu_open_url"
        name="OPEN MY URL"
        action="action_open_url"
    />
```